# Starling pauses when mouse leaves the stage area

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I have just started using starling (framework based on stage3d) and i am working on a simple ping pong game.

What my problem is the moment my mouse leaves the stage area everything just stops and resumes working when the mouse enter the area again. I guess this is some feature in the framework but how can i control it... is there some kind of event being fired..?? or is there some way to stop this feature ??

If its relevant i am using the 'TouchEvent.Touch' event and using the 'moved' phase. Any other details if required i am ready to provide....

Thanks.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i finally got the solution from the official starling forums.

As my mouse left the stage my 'touch' was getting null... hence the whole 'pausing' of game code.. I don't know why i didn't get an error of some kind.

Still if someone is facing something similar.. might check ur values are not null...